# CRON - chown and chgrp to a directory from root user to www-data

Tags: cron, cron-task

I am trying to change group and owner (from root to www-data) for a directory.

So I have set a cron on root which looks like this:

```
 0,5 * * * *   sudo /bin/chown -R www-data /var/www/pdf/ && sudo /bin/chgrp -R www-data /var/www/pdf/
```

But unfortunately it's not working. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 0,5 * * * *   sudo /bin/chown -R www-data /var/www/pdf/ && sudo /bin/chgrp -R www-data /var/www/pdf/

First off, the `chgrp` is redundant, you can manage the same with the `chown` command itself.

So instead of doing `sudo /bin/chown -R www-data /var/www/pdf/ && sudo /bin/chgrp -R www-data /var/www/pdf/`, you can do `sudo /bin/chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/pdf`

Now, instead of adding cron to a `user's crontab` with `sudo` / to systemwide cron using `/etc/cron.d`, add it to the root user's crontab using

```
sudo crontab -e
1,5 * * * * /bin/chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/pdf/
```